# What happens if I get approved for financing, but don't make the purchase?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit, financing, google-finance

I recently applied for financing to buy the Google Pixel. I was approved. When I went to place the order, the shipping time was a month away. I don't want to wait that long. I'll look at other buying options.

Now, what will happen to that financing account I just got approved for? Will they charge me? Will it affect my credit score? Am I in trouble here? Please help!

Comment: You probably have a hard pull on your credit report that's mostly meaningless, may affect your score for a couple months by a few points.  That's probably the extent of things.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: I'm in the United States

Comment: I would say that you "dodged a bullet" why in the world would you finance a phone?  Please make smarter financial decisions than that.

Comment: Don't a lot of people finance phones? I mean through carrier contracts and stuff?

Comment: Not always. I never would.

Comment: @PeteB. How many people do you think would buy an iPhone outright for $800?  $33 a month doesn't sound nearly as bad.  Plus it's interest free, right? ;)

Comment: Welcome to a very basic and needed financial lesson @user55483.  Financing things with massive depreciation such as phones, cars, and jewelry are very poor financial decisions.  Paying cash for most things will help make you wealthy.

Comment: @PeteB. Even cars? Come on! How are people supposed to afford $5k-10k at once? And also, jewellery like gold doesn't depreciate, does it?

Comment: @DStanley Yup, totally interest free

Comment: @user55483 That was sarcasm; the interest is baked into the retail price of the phone since almost no one buys the phone outright.

Comment: @user55483 "How are people supposed to afford $5k-10k at once?" save it up. "And also, jewellery like gold doesn't depreciate, does it?" Absolutely.  Compare the prices on eBay versus the prices in jewellery stores.  I hope your comments are sarcastic or you're going to be in debt the rest of your life.

Comment: @user55483 my son, who is a state trooper (relatively low pay for LEO in our state) and lives on his own, needed a car a few months ago.  For 10K he bought a very gently used Ford Escape which he paid for in cash.  He is also saving money to attend law school debt free.  Compared to my wife and I he drives a lot of car.  We have pretty high incomes, yet own 2 cars and a motorcycle with less than 10K in blue book value combined.  We prefer to invest the money.  Its what you deem important in life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen. It will not affect your credit score. You are not in trouble.  :)

Assuming that you didn't already agree to a purchase contract, you are not obligated to purchase simply because you had a pre-approval credit check done. However, even if you did, since they aren't shipping yet, you could probably cancel. If you are in doubt, talk to customer service to ensure that they aren't planning on shipping one to you.

They did check your credit report (known as a hard pull), and this does temporarily affect your credit score. However, it affects it the same whether you complete the purchase or not. If you have another credit check done with another seller, it will result in another hard pull, affecting your credit score a little more. But I wouldn't worry about a few hard pulls if you need to do some shopping. Just don't go overboard, and you'll be fine.

Comment: In your first sentence, would it better to say that it does affect your credit score, but only temporarily? Because you say that in your last paragraph...

Comment: @MichaelC. What I meant was that the hard pull is already done. Completing or cancelling the purchase at this point does not affect the score.

Comment: It's possible, that in this scenario no hard pull was done.  The Project Fi store uses a soft pull to determine credit IIRC, and does the hard pull only if you do the purchase via financing.  This is an unusual scenario and your results may vary.

Comment: The pull was not done by Google themselves, but a financial institution called Synchrony Bank. I don't know much about them